# converting json into pandas dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have `JSON` output that I would like to convert to pandas dataframe. I downloaded from a website via HTTPS and utilizing an API key. thanks much. here is what I coded:

```
json_data = vehicle_miles_traveled.json()

print(json_data)

{'request': {'command': 'series', 'series_id': 'STEO.MVVMPUS.A'}, 'series': [{'series_id': 'STEO.MVVMPUS.A', 'name': 'Vehicle Miles Traveled, Annual', 'units': 'million miles/day', 'f': 'A', 'description': 'Includes gasoline and diesel fuel vehicles', 'copyright': 'None', 'source': 'U.S. Energy Information Administration (EIA) - Short Term Energy Outlook', 'geography': 'USA', 'start': '1990', 'end': '2023', 'lastHistoricalPeriod': '2021', 'updated': '2022-03-08T12:39:35-0500', 'data': [['2023', 9247.0281671], ['2022', 9092.4575671], ['2021', 8846.1232877], ['2020', 7933.3907104], ['2019', 8936.3589041], ['2018', 8877.6027397], ['2017', 8800.9479452], ['2016', 8673.2431694], ['2015', 8480.4712329], ['2014', 8289.4684932], ['2013', 8187.0712329], ['2012', 8110.8387978], ['2011', 8083.2931507], ['2010', 8129.4958904], ['2009', 8100.7205479], ['2008', 8124.3387978], ['2007', 8300.8794521], ['2006', 8257.8520548], ['2005', 8190.2136986], ['2004', 8100.5163934], ['2003', 7918.4136986], ['2002', 7823.3123288], ['2001', 7659.2054795], ['2000', 7505.2622951], ['1999', 7340.9808219], ['1998', 7192.7780822], ['1997', 7014.7205479], ['1996', 6781.9699454], ['1995', 6637.7369863], ['1994', 6459.1452055], ['1993', 6292.3424658], ['1992', 6139.7595628], ['1991', 5951.2712329], ['1990', 5883.5643836]]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It hugely depends on your final goal. You could add all meta-data in a dataframe if you want to. I assume that you are interested in reading the data field into a dataframe.

We can just get those fields by accessing:

```
data = json_data['series'][0]['data']
# and pass them to the dataframe constructor. We can specify the column names as well!
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'other_col_name'])
```